# Empty preimage under homomorphism of finitely presented groups independent of ZFC

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic

Is there a homomorphism of finitely presented groups $f:G\to H$ and an element $h\in H$ such that the statement "$f^{-1}(h)$ is empty" is independent of ZFC?

Comment: It seems to me that any homomorphism between finitely presented groups is computable, whatever it means. Do I miss something?

Comment: We can take $f$ a morphism taking everything to identity. Then for appropriate $H$ we have that ZFC can't tell whether $H$ is nontrivial, so it can't check the nontriviality on all generators.

Comment: @Wojowu isn't the preimage of the identity always non-empty?

Comment: @Oniqa But ZFC won't be able to prove that these elements are or aren't identity.

Comment: @Wojowu but the identity is certainly getting sent to the identity

Comment: This question seems to confuse the issue of algorithm decidability with independence from ZFC

Comment: From the algorithmic point of view since every thing is fixed, there is no input, the answer is no.  From the ZFC point if view my guess would also be no but I don't know set theory

Comment: @YCor I think you are right. I got confused there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, as a consequence of [my answer to your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/390821/1946).

Namely, in that answer, we have a finite group presentation $H$ and a word $h$ such that the question $h=1$ in $H$ is independent of ZFC. So if we take $G$ to be trivial and $f:G\to H$ the unique homomorphism, we have the statement "$f^{-1}(h)$ is nonempty" being independent of ZFC.

The general lesson of that answer supplies also an answer to Benjamin Steinberg's comment here concerning a confusion between computable undecidability and ZFC or logical undecidability. The general lesson, which I argue on the other post, is that every computably undecidable enumerable decision problem is saturated with logical undecidability. So the two notions of undecidability are actually intimately connected.

Comment: But the independence from ZFC thing seems to make some assumptions about cardinals

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg The $\Sigma_1$-correctness was only for the very general fact. Meanwhile, the example at the end of my other answer produces a ZFC independent instance assuming only Con(ZFC), which is required in order to have anything independent of ZFC.